# Remove chapter number from Bibliography

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, numbering, koma-script

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.6cm,rmargin=2.6cm,headheight=1.3cm,headsep=1cm}
\pagestyle{headings}

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{scrpage2,datetime,tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

%%% OPTIONS
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
%\setlist{nolistsep}
\tabulinesep=^1.5mm_1.5mm
\tikzset{>=latex}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

%%% DEFINITIONS
\newenvironment{myfont}{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}{\par}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Wrap}{Wrap}
\addto\captionsenglish{  \renewcommand{\contentsname}  {Table of Contents} }

%%% HEADERS
\makeatletter
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\sffamily\bfseries\small }
\clearscrheadfoot
\rohead{line1 \linebreak \@normalcr[-9pt] line2 \linebreak\@normalcr[-2pt] \normalfont\sffamily\footnotesize{line3 \linebreak\@normalcr[-49pt]}}
\lohead{\rule{1.5cm}{1.5cm}\vspace{0.05cm}}
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\makeatother

%%% FOOTERS
\lofoot [docname.pdf] {docname.pdf}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{chapter}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{appendix1}
\end{appendices}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

I end up having "Bibliography" as second chapter.

How can I prevent it?
Have I messed up something with those packages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Option 1: replace

```
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

with

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

See section 2 of the `tocbibind` documentation in case `numbib` is not self-explanatory.

Option 2: As you're using a `KOMA-Script` class, don't load the `tocbibind` package at all; instead add the class option `bibliography=totoc`.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much! :) (used the second solution, btw)

Comment: Option 3: The class option `toc=bib` (KOMA-Script 3.11b).